# Is it possible to use Gitlab and Wordpress container linked to only one Mariadb container?

Tags: wordpress, postgresql, docker, gitlab, mariadb

I have an instance of Gitlab running on my host, it's composed by: a Gitlab container, a PostgreSQL container and a Redis container. Gitlab is linked to Postgresql and Redis . Also, there's an instance of Wordpress running, it's a Wordpress and a Mariadb container. Wordpress is linked to Mariadb.
As both Gitlab and Wordpress needs a database container to store data, basically i'd like to use just one database container. In this case, i'd like to use only the Mariadb container to store data from both Gitlab and Wordpress. Is it possible? If it is, how could i do it?

Comment: You have to check the documentation of those packages you use. In general most applications can work based on different types of database management systems, as long as those offer a reasonable standard conform service, since the query language is standardized. However the systems are not really identical, that is why the database management has to be supported by the application. That is documented, you will also find an explanation about the steps you have to take.  It makes much more sense to look into the documentation than to ask here.